# Adam 4050 Data acquisition module

Tags: python, rs485, data-acquisition

Is there any one who worked on Adam 4050 data acquisition module? Any idea on connecting Adam module with Adam utility software??

If so can help me on how to achieve communication using RS485 communication using python. Sample codes will be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.